# How to play youtube video automatically without click on play button

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

how can i play youtube video automatically i.e without click on play button on webpage when page is being loaded.

```
        function ShowModalPopup() {
        var url = $get("<%=txtUrl.ClientID %>").value;
        url = url.split('v=')[1];
        $get("video").src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + url
        $find("mpe").show();
        return false;
```

Comment: From a user experience point of view, why do you want to do this? I hate sites that get active without my consent.

Comment: If it's because they clicked something else that made the modal show, that would be a valid user experience.  Anyway, check out the player API https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls. As you can see, its definitely possible to play a video using javascript.

Comment: @Umesh kumar did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just add one parameter to your URL i.e. `autoplay=1`

Your calling url should be like this

```
 $get("video").src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + url +"autoplay=1";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control the video using the YouTube player API as seen here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls

It's as simple as player.playVideo();

Answer (score 2):

try to add get parameter - autoplay=1

Answer (score 1):

Append `autoplay=1` to the url of the embed url.